# TemplateDoesNotExist at /student/student_form/

Tags: python, django

When i  try   "http://127.0.0.1:8000/student/student_form/"
it  gives  an error  like TemplateDoesNotExist at /student/student_form/
Please help me  to  resolve these  issues and  thanks  in  advance

This  is  my  templates code in  settings.py   file

```
 TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

This  is  my  views.py  file

```
def student_list(request):
    return render(request,"student_list.html")


def student_form(request):
    return render(request, "student_form.html")


def student_delete(request):
    return
```

This  is  my  url.py files

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('student/', include('student_reg.urls'))
    ]


    urlpatterns = [
        path('student_form/', views.student_form),
        path('student_list/', views.student_list),
    ]
```

This  is  my  project structure

```
├── CRUD
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── student_reg
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-35.pyc
    │       └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── admin.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── models.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
    │   └── views.cpython-35.pyc
    ├── templates
    │   ├── base.html
    │   ├── student_from.html
    │   └── student_list.html
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file name is wrong.Your file name actually `student_from.html` but in your view `student_form.html`.Please change this.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify every directory you want in your settings. In your case like so:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'student_reg/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Django just needs a place to search. :)

Happy coding!

Comment: .
├── CRUD
│   └── __pycache__
└── student_reg
    ├── migrations
    │   └── __pycache__
    ├── __pycache__
    └── templates

this  is  my current project structure

Comment: Can you add your traceback?

Comment: Should work according to your traceback. Is it the typo in your filename? in your example it says student_from.html and in your traceback it is searching for student_form.html